# No Grub menu in dual boot after reset

Tags: grub2

So I have Windows 10 and Kubuntu 20.04 dual boot, and that works great. But, when I restart my laptop, from any system, I don't get to the grub menu, but it directly goes to Kubuntu. This happens ONLY after reset. If I shutdown the laptop and start it again, I get to the grub. And this is how I do it when I have to switch systems. As you can see on my image, it exists, it works, but only after a shutdown. Tried boto-reapir from live usb, no luck. Any ideas how to fix it?

https://prnt.sc/JmeCCMWUyzlZ

Comment: Something does not look right. Windows in BIOS mode must have boot on primary partition, not sda5 which with MBR(msdos) must be a logical partition. Or from ESP - efi system partition if UEFI using gpt partitioning. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/
 Note that grub only boots

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/7QnsgwHHdZ/

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode? And you have set grub timeout to 0 ( line 237) which means you do not even have time to press escape key to get grub menu. I use 3, but also change this in grub to always show menu: `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`

Comment: Yes, uefi. There was no grub file at the default location, so I copied the default one there. I can delete it. But even with that set to 0, I still have 10 seconds to choose at the grub menu. I've just checked. This is of course when I start my laptop when it was previously turned off. If I now restart it, I will not see the grub menu.

Comment: The fact is, there is a menu there every time, even when I don't see it. I've just tried to click 2 times down and Enter and I started Windows 10. :D

Comment: Which grub file was missing? Did you run `sudo update-grub` ? Or are you getting grub.cfg.new which says it has a typo? That would be a problem. It may be better to just totally reinstall grub, which will overwrite your settings. Then manually restore one by one your setting changes to find what change you made is issue.

Comment: Before I asked here, I was about to edit grub and try some struff but there was no grub file to be found at /etc/default/grub so I copied the default one from /usr/share/grub/default/grub.
I did what you asked from me, did the sudo update-grub, reboot, no luck. Still black screen (but with the grub menu behind it, I can blindly click stuff).

Comment: The version of grub in report is not a default, so did you edit it after restoring it, or did not not really copy the default one to /etc/default/grub?

Comment: This is what I did exactly:
sudo cp /usr/share/grub/default/grub /etc/default/

And after that I just edited the timeout line.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the boot order in BIOS (UEFI) settings.
More options here:

- https://www.makeuseof.com/fix-grub-not-showing-in-dual-boot-setup

Comment: The boot order is fine. I mean, is the boot order ok when I shutdown my laptop and start it again? In that case evrything is working fine.